Show/hide some text in larger text
I'm trying to show/hide some text (a highlight) in the middle of a paragraph. These criteria are essential:

I need the method to be flexible to work on a single line or multi-line.
And I need it to not mess with the rest of the paragraph's text line-height.

Below are what I have so far but neither is quite right. Version 1 has the transition I would prefer i.e. width of the <mark> tag reducing to zero and using an overflow: hidden to mask the text as it is reducing is size. The problem with this is it can't be multi-line. Version 2 is a compromise that reduces font-size: 0px; but can be multi-line.
Is there any solution to getting this to work (looking like version 1 but functioning like version 2)? Or is there another solution to this? (I have also tried transform: scaleX(0); and this does not work).


body
{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.section
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 210px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.paragraph
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.paragraph1
{
    background: #00ffff;
}

.paragraph2
{
    background: #00ffff;
}


/* version 1 */
.mark1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 21px;
    transition: all 1.0s;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre;
}

.mark1 span
{
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    height: 23px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #cccccc;
}

.mark1.hidden
{
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 1.0s;
}


/* version 2 */
.mark2
{
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1.0s;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    background: #00ff00;
}

.mark2 span
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: #cccccc;
}

.mark2.hidden
{
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: all 1.0s;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>example</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>


<button onclick="
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mark1');

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
collection[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
}
">toggle version 1</button>

<div class="section">
<div class="paragraph paragraph1">
Lorem Ipsum is<mark class="mark1"> <span>simply dummy text of</span></mark> the printing and typesetting industry. <mark class="mark1"><span>Lorem Ipsum</span> </mark>has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>



<button onclick="
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mark2');

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
collection[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
}

">toggle version 2</button>

<div class="section">
<div class="paragraph paragraph2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the<mark class="mark2"> <span>industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span></mark>, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>




I don't see how it could be done with CSS, when you need it to be multi-line. You probably need a JavaScript solution, that keeps removing (and re-adding, for the other direction) one character of the text after the other.

Yes I've considered the letter-by-letter approach but this will be nightmarish to implement. You can see I'm calling it on all of the classlist - this is because it will ultimately target many mark tags at once. So I would need all of the texts stored in the javascript, lots of typewriter scripts all working at once.

This code allows you to dynamically input any text, then specify the highlighted parts, and afterwards you can copy it or choose to hide or display it as you wish.
I tried to write comments for the codes.


function updateWordList() {
  let text = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  let words = text.split(/\s+/);
  let wordListDiv = document.getElementById('wordList');
  wordListDiv.innerHTML = '';

    // Create a checkbox for each word
  words.forEach((word, index) => {
    if (word) {
      let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
      checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
      checkbox.id = `word-${index}`;
      checkbox.value = word;
      checkbox.onchange = updateHighlight;

      let label = document.createElement('label');
      label.htmlFor = `word-${index}`;
      label.innerText = word;

      wordListDiv.appendChild(checkbox);
      wordListDiv.appendChild(label);
      wordListDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
  });


  document.getElementById('resultText').innerText = text;
}


/**
 * Updates the highlighted text based on the selected words from the word list.
 * This function checks each word's checkbox, and if checked, highlights that word in the output.
 * 
 * @function updateHighlight
 */
function updateHighlight() {
  let text = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  let words = text.split(/\s+/);

  let highlightedText = words.map((word, index) => {
    let checkbox = document.getElementById(`word-${index}`);
    if (checkbox && checkbox.checked) {
      return `<span class="highlight" data-index="${index}">${word}</span>`;
    } else {
      return word;
    }
  }).join(' ');

  document.getElementById('resultText').innerHTML = highlightedText;
}


/**
 * Copies the currently displayed text (with or without highlights) to the clipboard.
 * It extracts the plain text from the result, creates a temporary textarea,
 * copies the content, and then removes the temporary element.
 * 
 * @function copyHighlightedText
 */

function copyHighlightedText() {
  let resultDiv = document.getElementById('resultText');
  let tempTextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
  tempTextarea.value = resultDiv.innerText;
  document.body.appendChild(tempTextarea);
  tempTextarea.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(tempTextarea);
  alert('متن کپی شد!');
}


/**
 * Toggles the visibility of the highlighted words in the result text.
 * When the words are hidden, they are removed from the display but stored in memory,
 * and can be restored upon re-toggling.
 * 
 * @function toggleHighlights
 */


let highlightsVisible = true;
let hiddenWords = [];

function toggleHighlights() {
  let resultDiv = document.getElementById('resultText');
  if (highlightsVisible) {
    let highlightedSpans = resultDiv.querySelectorAll('.highlight');
    hiddenWords = [];
    highlightedSpans.forEach(span => {
      let wordIndex = span.getAttribute('data-index');
      hiddenWords.push({ index: wordIndex, word: span.innerText });
      span.classList.add('hidden-word');
    });
    highlightsVisible = false;
  } else {
    hiddenWords.forEach(hidden => {
      let span = resultDiv.querySelector(`.highlight[data-index="${hidden.index}"]`);
      if (span) {
        span.classList.remove('hidden-word');
      }
    });
    highlightsVisible = true;
  }
}
.highlight {
    background-color: rgb(255, 238, 0);
  }

  .hidden-word {
    display: none;
  }

  #inputText {
    width: 36%;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 150px;
  }

  #copy {
    width: 26%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(111, 111, 253);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }

  #copy:hover {
    background-color: rgb(77, 77, 252);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #showHide {
    width: 10%;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(13, 189, 0);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
  }

  #showHide:hover {
    background-color: rgb(2, 148, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
  }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dynamic Highlight with Word Selection</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Dynamic word highlight</h1>

  <textarea id="inputText" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter your text ..." oninput="updateWordList()"></textarea>
  <br><br>

  <div id="wordList"></div>
  <br><br>
  <!-- buttons -->
  <button id="copy" onclick="copyHighlightedText()">COPY Highlight Words</button>
  <button id="showHide" onclick="toggleHighlights()">Show / hide words</button>

  <!-- SHOW RESULT -->
  <div id="resultText" style="margin-top: 20px; white-space: pre-wrap;"></div>

  <!-- linked js -->
  <script src="script-MSI.js"></script>

</body>

</html>




In this situation, you don't need to deploy CSS presentational effects.
Instead you can:

use .split('') to build a letter-by-letter array of the highlighted text
manipulate that array
replace the highlighted text in the paragraph with the contents of the manipulated array


Working Example:


const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggleButton');
const mark = document.querySelector('mark');
const markedText = mark.textContent;
let markedTextArray = markedText.split('');

const toggleHighlight = (e) => {
  
  if (markedTextArray.length === 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < markedText.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        markedTextArray.push(markedText[i]);
        mark.textContent = markedTextArray.join('');
      }, (20 * i));
    } 
  } else {  
    for (let i = (markedText.length - 1); (i + 1) > 0; i--) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        markedTextArray.pop();
        mark.textContent = markedTextArray.join('');
      }, (20 * i));
    }  
  }
}  


toggleButton.addEventListener('click', toggleHighlight);
section {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 210px;
}

.paragraph {
  padding: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: rgb(223, 223, 223);
}
<button type="button" class="toggleButton">Toggle Highlight</button>

<section>
<p class="paragraph">Lorem Ipsum<mark> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book</mark>. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</section>




this is clever. I hadn't thought of testing position according to the mark and then using the letter-by-letter technique. The effect is great - will test tomorrow to see if I can get this working for me.

This doesn't solve my issue unfortunately as it's specific to one highlight in the paragraph. I need the button to remove and return all highlights, which is why I was using the for loop andcollection[i].classList.toggle('hidden'); instead of simply targeting the one class instance. Since it uses one variable markedTextArray to store I don't see how it could be adapted easily to store many. Have upvoted though as it is clever.

@garettlynchirl Re: "it's specific to one highlight in the paragraph" It's a proof of concept. Your homework is to create an object of arrays in which each key of the object matches an individual class (or id) attached to the relevant <mark>. Then you'll see you can have any number of <mark> elements and the text of each will always be recorded. You'll need to take things further yourself from here onwards, but please ask below if you have any further questions. Using the example above, you can do this.

To archive this you need alteast 2 elements
<mark class="mark1">
    <span class="mark-placeholder">simply dummy text of</span>
    <span class="mark-highlight">simply dummy text of</span>
</mark>

At this point you can animate width on mark-placeholder
and transform mark-hightlight as you wish without interupt layout since its absolute


body
{
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 21px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.section
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 210px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

.paragraph
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.paragraph1
{
    background: #00ffff;
}

.paragraph2
{
    background: #00ffff;
}


/* version 1 */
.mark1
{
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 21px;
    transition: all 1.0s;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre;
}

.mark1.hidden
{
  width: 0px;
  transition: all 1.0s;
}

.mark-placeholder
{
position: relative;
opacity: 0;
display: inline-block;
}

.mark-hightlight
{
box-sizing: border-box;
display: block;
color: red;
background-color: #cccccc;
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0%;
top: -0;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
transform: translateY(-10%);
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>example</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open Sans' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>


<button onclick="
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mark1');

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
collection[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
}
">toggle version 1</button>

<div class="section">
<div class="paragraph paragraph1">
Lorem Ipsum is<mark class="mark1"> <span class="mark-placeholder">simply dummy text of</span><span class="mark-hightlight">simply dummy text of</span></mark> the printing and typesetting industry. has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>



<button onclick="
const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('mark2');

for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
collection[i].classList.toggle('hidden');
}

">toggle version 2</button>

<div class="section">
<div class="paragraph paragraph2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the<mark class="mark2"> <span>industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</span></mark>, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>




Do you mean, “To achieve this…”?

@Karol_Ch many thanks, this is the simplest solution and possibly the only one I will be able to implement (specific context not ability). Will test this but will this extend over multiple lines - I have a feeling it might not.

@Karol_Ch unfortunately this won't work. It's too specific to one text length as the <mark> uses a fixed width so isn't adaptable.
